# Set values and display Text in Spinner

Tags: java, android

I have Spinner for choose file from assets by the string like this but I want to display other names in Spinner  .. now work fine but show name pic.jpg .. I want text and value

text

```
String s = {"picture car" , "picture mobile"}
```

and value

```
String[] spinnerValue = {"pic.jpg", "pic2.jpg"};


 spinnerDropDownView =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(test.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spinnerValue);
        spinnerDropDownView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What? Whats happening here?

Comment: Do you want to show both `text` and `value` in spinner?

Comment: You need to implement Custom Spinner Adapter. Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-spinner/).

Answer (score 7):

use Spinner adapter with key value pair pojo model 
see below code for more detail

Step 1 : Create POJO class which will take care of key and

```
public class Country {

private String id;
private String name;

public Country(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


//to display object as a string in spinner
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Country){
        Country c = (Country )obj;
        if(c.getName().equals(name) && c.getId()==id ) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Note : toString() method is important as it is responsible for displaying the data in spinner,you can modify toString() as per your need

Step 2 : Prepare data to be loaded in spinner

```
 private void setData() {

    ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add countries

    countryList.add(new Country("1", "India"));
    countryList.add(new Country("2", "USA"));
    countryList.add(new Country("3", "China"));
    countryList.add(new Country("4", "UK"));

    //fill data in spinner 
    ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Country>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countryList);
    spinner_country.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner_country.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(myItem));//Optional to set the selected item.    
}
```

Step 3 : and finally get selected item's key and value in onitemselected listener method of spinner

```
spinner_country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             Country country = (Country) parent.getSelectedItem();
             Toast.makeText(context, "Country ID: "+country.getId()+",  Country Name : "+country.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {    
        }
    });
```

Comment: how getSelectedItem to use anywhere in activity ?

Comment: OnItemSelected you can get selected item.

Comment: What is "context" and "myItem"? How to set the "spinner_country" variable value?